# Editor/IDE that can open random java source file and provide intellisense

Tags: java, ide, editor

Is there a free editor/IDE that an open any random java source file and provide intellisense features? Eclipse is a common free editor/IDE but it requires you to create a project first.

Comment: Questions asking to recommend tools are [explicitly off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) at StackOverflow (see item 5 at that page). You could try at http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com, but you should [be more specific about what you're trying to find](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336), or else your question won't do well there.

Answer (score 2):

You should not mix simple editors that only allow to edit source files and full IDE that allow to compile, run, test or debug full applications.

In the first category, you find emacs, vim or notepad++ all with syntax highlighting. In the second, you have eclipse or NetBeans. The latter is able to edit a random java file, but if the file imports non standard (JDK) modules, the IDE will have difficulties to find them.

Comment: By your criteria, Emacs /is/ a full IDE, as it does allow compiling, running, testing and debugging full applications from within the application...

Answer (score 1):

Most IDEs can provide basic intellisense, such as syntax and color coding of reserved words, but if you don't have a project it is near impossible to determine if an import can be found (for example).

Simple and easy editor? Try ideone.com with basic intellisense.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use notepad++ choosing JAVA?
http://notepad-plus-plus.org/

Comment: That's only for Windows.

Answer (score 1):

My advice is SublimeText, shareware available on Windows, Mac OS and Linux!
It is my favourite editor.
You can download it at: http://www.sublimetext.com/2